# 403 forbidden error while getting javascripts under root folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I have javascripts folder under root folder , its all workig fine till now. Suddenly it started giving me the following error for all the javascripts under scripts folder.

I the only change i made today is , deployed some files under website root directory which are asp files. I didn't deploy any files to scripts folder at all.

I saw in firebug net panel and i got the same error there.

***The page cannot be displayedYou have attempted to execute a CGI, ISAPI, or other executable program from a directory that does not allow programs to be executed.
Please try the following:***

Contact the Web site administrator if you believe this directory should allow execute access.
HTTP Error 403.1 - Forbidden: Execute access is denied.
Internet Information Services (IIS)
Technical Information (for support personnel)

Comment: Check ACL permissions for files and containing folder.

Comment: what are ACL permisions??? is it folder readonly ?? i changed that and even parent folder but its agian getting checked.

Comment: @jakum , thanks for your reply , i found the issue and updated as comment below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You web server is set up to think that .js files are server-side JavaScript and you are in a directory with Execute permission. You need the Execute permission if you have .asp there.  Go to your IIS settings and find the list of handlers (not mime-types) and make sure that .js isn't listed.

Or, you could just move the .js files to a folder without execute permission in IIS.

Comment: you are absolutely right , i was doing some IIS changes on a virtual directory to add mapping for js and .css to do some aggregation, by mistake i added on the root. Thanks alot its working now.

Answer (score 0):

This error appeared when there was no file specified.  Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/"></script>  <!-- broken -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/<filename>.js"></script>
```