# 403 Error using JavaScript to access folder

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms, directory

In a .Net Web Forms project  am trying to use JavaScript to display all images in a folder. Using the following script gives me a 403 error

```
<script>
    var dir = "fullimages/";
    var filext = ".jpg";
    $.ajax({
        url: dir,
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).find("a:contains(" + filext + ")").each(function () {
                var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http:///", "");
                $("body").append($("<img src=" + dir + filename + "></img>"));
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

But I am not quite sure why? I have checked around the site and found the following suggestion [403 forbidden error while getting javascripts under root folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288016/403-forbidden-error-while-getting-javascripts-under-root-folder). In my case JS is not on the list of handlers.

Answer (score 0):

If I have got this right your trying to run Javascript on the server side. Are you using any particular framework, node JS for example? 
Secondly what server architecture are you running, windows (IIS) / linux (APACHE, N GINX) etc...?

From having a brief read of your linked question, have you tried moving this script into the fullimages directory and then request that?

Comment: i am using asp.net and trying to use a javascript to access images from a folder. Is this not allowed?

Comment: I have also just tried moving the script into a folder and tried to request it. I still get a 403 forbidden

Comment: So are you using the above code within a web form? If so can you use a conical URL for the directory, even if it's just http://localhost:8888/~/fullimages/

Comment: using `var dir = "/~/fullimages/";` results in a 404

Comment: Sorry I meant but in the fully qualified path, the ~ might not be enough to resolve it. Also if you put a break point in your global.asax  class, you should see what the request comes in as.